# Attempt to re-connect jdbc connect after database(sysbase) service restart

Tags: java, sybase, tomcat8

I am working with a Sybase database. When I restart the database, Tomcat is not auto connecting to it.
It works fine when I restart the Tomcat service after successfully restarting the sysbase DB.
I am using a property file and from that file I am passing info to tomcat xml file.

```
connection.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:10.0.0.2:20000/TestDB
connection.username=test connection.password=
connection.password.type=encrypted pool.initialSize=50 pool.maxIdle=50
pool.minIdle=25 pool.maxActive=100 pool.suspectTimeout=60
pool.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=90000
pool.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=90000 pool.validationInterval=30000
pool.removeAbandoned=true pool.removeAbandonedTimeout=300
pool.logAbandoned=true pool.testOnBorrow=true pool.jmxEnabled=true
pool.jdbcInterceptors=SlowQueryReportJmx(threshold=5000)
```

All values are set in `server.xml` file with `validationQuery="SELECT 1"`.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: do you have any logs indicating an error?

Comment: yes , i have processing failed; nested exception is com.ge.hcit.id.exception.DbUnavailableException: null] with root cause
 com.ge.hcit.id.exception.DbUnavailableException: null

Comment: and you are certain that the database is running when the tomcat server starts? you wrote that the db restart was successful. can you elaborate on the steps taken to achieve the error?

Comment: Yes JoSSte, sysbase is running

Comment: system there i installed sybase db , i restarted complete system and using Aqua-stdio(db connection tool) i checked it running and query giving result .

Comment: 1. start db system 2.start tomcat service 3. checked application running  3.restart only db system 4. check application running . here is the steps and aftre 4th step i am getting error on tomcat error log

Comment: any solution JoSSte?